# Extrael datos del localstorage para realizar cáculos

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

Estoy intentando obtener los datos almacenados en el localStorage, para calcular Nota Promedio, Nota Mayor y Nota Menor, sin embargo no me muestra el resultado, como tampoco me generar ningún error.

Mi código

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/estilos.css'/>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amaranth' rel='stylesheet'>
        <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

    function editarEstudiante(codigo){
        var estudiante;
        for (var i = 0; i<localStorage.length; i++){
            var clave = localStorage.key(i);
            if (clave == codigo) {
                estudiante = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem(clave));

                $("#codigo").val(estudiante.codigo);
                $("#nombre").val(estudiante.nombre);
                $("#nota").val(estudiante.nota);
            }
        }
    }

    function listarEstudiantes(){
        var tabla = "";
        var parrafo1 = $("#p1");

        tabla += '<table border="1">';
        tabla += '<tr>';
        tabla += '<th>CODIGO</th>';
        tabla += '<th>NOMBRE</th>';
        tabla += '<th>NOTA</th>';
        tabla += '<th>EDITAR</th>';
        tabla += '<th>ELIMINAR</th>';
        tabla += '</tr>';

        for (var i=0; i<localStorage.length; i++){
            var clave = localStorage.key(i);
            var estudiante = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem(clave));

            tabla += '<tr>';
            tabla += '<td>'+estudiante.codigo+'</td>';
            tabla += '<td>'+estudiante.nombre+'</td>';
            tabla += '<td>'+estudiante.nota+'</td>';
            tabla += '<td><button onclick="editarEstudiante(\''+estudiante.codigo+'\');">Editar</button></td>';
            tabla += '<td><button onclick="eliminarEstudiante(\''+estudiante.codigo+'\');">Eliminar</button></td>';
            tabla += '</tr>';
            }
        tabla += '</table>';
        $(parrafo1).html(tabla);
    }

    function eliminarEstudiante(codigo){
        localStorage.removeItem(codigo);
        listarEstudiantes();
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var contador;
        if(localStorage.length>0){
            contador = localStorage.length+1
        }else{
            contador = 1;
        }

        $("#codigo").val(contador);

        $("#boton1").click(function(){
            var codigo = $("#codigo").val();
            var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
            var nota = $("#nota").val();

            var estudiante = {
                codigo:codigo,
                nombre:nombre,
                nota:nota
            };

            localStorage.setItem(codigo,JSON.stringify(estudiante));
            contador = localStorage.length + 1;

    listarEstudiantes();
    restablecer();

 });

  $("#boton2").click(function(){
    restablecer(9);
  });

  function restablecer(){
    $("#codigo").val(contador);
    $("#nombre").val("");
    $("#nota").val("");
  }

    listarEstudiantes();
    $("#codigo").val();

});

$("#boton3").click(function(){
    var acumulador = 0.0;
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    acumulador += localStorage[i].nota;
    }
    var promedio = acumulador / localStorage.length;

    alert("La nota promedio es: " + promedio);

});
</script>
```

## Registro de Estudiantes

```
        <form>
                Codigo:
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="codigo" disabled>
                <br>Nombre:
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="nombre">
                <br>Nota:
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="nota">
        </form>

        <button id="boton1">Registrar Estudiante</button>
            <button id="boton2">Restablecer</button>
            <button id="boton3">Mostrar Nota Promedio</button>
            <button id="boton4">Mostrar Nota Mayor</button>
            <button id="boton5">Mostrar Nota Menor</button>


        <p id="p1"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu función que calcula el promedio tiene los siguientes errores:

- `localStorage.length` devuelve el total de claves guardadas, no el nombre de las claves. Para solucionar este error debes usar [`localStorage.key(i)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/key), el cual te devolverá el nombre de clave en la posición `i`. Una vez obtenida la clave `key`, puedes usar [`localStorage.getItem(key)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) para obtener el valor de esta.
- El valor almacenado para cada clave es un `JSON String` (*ver: `localStorage.setItem(codigo,JSON.stringify(estudiante));`*), es decir, que antes de intentar acceder directamente a una propiedad, por ejemplo, `estudiante.nota`, debes usar [`JSON.parse(data)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse) para recuperar el `object`.
- Por ultimo, cuando obtienes `nota = $("#nota").val()`, este valor es un `string`, por lo que debes de convertilo a `int (parseInt())` o `float (parseFloat())` para poder sumar

### Solución:

Podrías corregir lo anteriormente mencionado de la siguiente forma:

```
$("#boton3").click(function() {
  var acumulador = 0.0,
    key, data, estudiante;
  for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    key = localStorage.key(i); // Clave donde esta guardada la info del Est.
    data = localStorage.getItem(key); // Info del Est. en formato JSON
    estudiante = JSON.parse(data); // Objecto estudiante
    acumulador += parseInt(estudiante.nota, 10); // Nota en formato entero
  }
  var promedio = acumulador / localStorage.length;

  alert("La nota promedio es: " + promedio);

});
```

Comment: Realice los cambios, sin embargo, no me muestra el alert, de hecho, presion el boton y no pasa nada, ni resultado, ni error

Comment: @Gustavo, te dejo [una demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Socramg/643sn5e2/) para que compruebes que realizando los cambios propuestos aquí debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Para recuperar datos del localStorage uso: por ejemplo

```
var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
```

Te aconsejo que mires este enlace: [Storing Data on The Client with LocalStorage](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/storing-data-on-the-client-with-localstorage) sobre como usar el localStorage, es muy útil.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#boton3").click(function(){
        var total = 0;
        var promedio = 0;

        for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){

            var clave = localStorage.key(i);
            var estudiante = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem(clave));

            total += parseInt(estudiante.nota, 10);
            promedio = total / localStorage.length; 
        }


    alert(promedio)

});
```